# Slow and tiring. How to understand?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In a book in the section of related vocabulary (describing weather section) they provided some useful phrases and here's one of them:

> pace of journeys slow and tiring

Here's how I understand what it might mean. We could say

> I'm going to take a nap as soon as we get back home. The pace of our
>   today's journey was really slow and tiring.

First of all, does it sound correct? If so, am I right in thinking that **slow and tiring** here means ***with low speed and boring so we get tired***. I'm actually confused by the fact that there two completely unrelated adjectives. Slow is about speed and tiring is about your feeling.

And here in the phrase (`pace of journeys slow and tiring`) pace already means speed. It's difficul to imagine how pace might be tiring, really...

Comment: Do they give any more context?  Is that one phrase?  It's hard for me to imagine a context in which I would literally say "pace of journeys slow and tiring".

Comment: @stangdon Unfortunately, yes, it appears isolated in a student book. It's an example of a phrase that might be useful for describing climate.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking the meaning of the adjective "slow". Let's say there is a bullet train which can run at 300 km per hour and there is a very slow train with the maximum speed of only 50 km per hour. Which train do you think would make you more tired? Of course, a slower train would make you more tired as it takes more time to reach one place from another.

You should understand the phrase as follows:

> Pace of journeys is slow. Since it is slow, it makes you feel more
>   tired than when the pace is faster (less slow). That's why the pace is **tiring**.

Tiring means:

> Causing one to need rest or sleep.

Answer (score 1):

*Tiring* is not a feeling; *tired* is.

> The pace of the journey is **tiring**.
>   ***=*** The pace of the journey is **making you feel tired**.

On a more general note:

> The pace of the journey is **slow** and **tiring**.
>   **=** The pace of the journey is so slow that most people will feel tired.
>     **=** The slow pace of the journey can make people feel tired.